# Linear independence of sine

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Is there any easy way to prove that $\sin(u_1 x)$, $\sin(u_2 x), \ldots, \sin(u_n x)$ for distinct $u_1, u_2, \ldots u_n$ are linearly independent?

Comment: You have to specify the definition of inner product on the Hilbert space you are working on.

Comment: @AbishankaSaha linear independence does not depend on inner product definition, does it?

Comment: sorry, I read the problem wrong, I thought you need to show that they are orthogonal.

Comment: You can use @AbishankaSaha's observation if all of the $u$ are rational, say with common denominator $m$, by integrating $\sin^2(u_k x)$ on an interval of length $2\pi m$ (which by positivity gives a positive value), supposing some $\sin(u_k x)$ can be realized as a linear combination of the other functions, substituting the linear combination for one factor of $\sin (u_k x)$ in the intergral, and using orthogonality to conclude that the integral is zero, a contradiction.

Comment: If you know Fourier transform try to work on the coefficients of sinusoidal function.

Answer (score 0):

Provided that none of the $u_k$ are negatives of another $u_j$, this follows immediately from the linearity of the Fourier transform, which maps functions $\sin(u_k x)$ to a linear combination of Dirac delta distributions at points unique to the respective parameters $u_k$: The Fourier transforms are linearly independent, and thus so are the original continuous functions.

Comment: Or, you could use the Laplace transform to avoid $\delta$ functions. The Laplace transforms have poles at different places in the complex plane, which also shows linear independence.